# How do I overwrite AlternatingRowBackground inside the DataGridRow template?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

I'm creating a DataGrid with rows with AlternatingRowBackground property. However, the data in the rows must be amended and that takes some time.

I'm trying to make the background color of the rows appear light gray while they are initializing. Here's what I'm doing in the RowTemplate:

```
<ControlTemplate.Triggers>
    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Initialized}" Value="False">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightGray"/>
    </DataTrigger>
</ControlTemplate.Triggers>
```

But this does not work for the odd rows which still have the color specified in AlternatingRowBackground.

How do I overwrite this so all rows which are not initialized appear light gray?

Comment: Did you try to put this DataTrigger in the template for the alternating rows too? My guess is that the Template for the alternate row is applied after the template with the datatrigger.

Comment: No, I didn't do that. How do I do this?

Comment: Sorry I stated that in the wrong order. Have a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3614918/563088 you could try to put the datatrigger together with the setter for the alternating row background in a single style.

Answer (score 7):

I had the same problem and worked for me next:
Set the AlternatingRowBackground in the style, but not in the DataGrid.

```
    <Grid.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="dg" TargetType="DataGrid">
            <Setter Property="AlternatingRowBackground" Value="Orange"/>
            <Setter Property="AutoGenerateColumns" Value="False"/>
        </Style>
    </Grid.Resources>
    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource one}, Path=Persons}" Style="{StaticResource dg}">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Width="*" Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Path=Name}"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGrid.RowStyle>
            <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Mature}" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightGray"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </DataGrid.RowStyle>
    </DataGrid>
```