# WPF DataGrid AlternatingRowBackground and RowStyle precedence

Tags: wpf, wpfdatagrid

How do I make my `RowStyle` to get applied after `AlternatingRowBackground`? I want items, having `IsOrange` as `true` to have `Orange` background regardless of alternating row background, which isn't the case currently.

**XAML:**

```
<DataGrid Name="g"
    AlternatingRowBackground="Blue" 
    AlternationCount="2" 
    ...
    SelectionMode="Single">
    <DataGrid.RowStyle>
        <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsOrange}" Value="Y">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Orange" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.RowStyle>
    ...
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: Where IsOrange Property Located, Is It Located Directly on Window Context??

Comment: I have an viewmodel SomethingWhichCanBeOrangeViewModel which has boolean IsRange property. My grid has it's ItemsSource set to ObservableCollection<SomethingWhichCanBeOrangeViewModel>.

Comment: Okay, so you are sure that your property is accessible in your DataGrid.

Comment: @MoHaKa It does work for the rows, which background isn't affected by alternating, i.e. having 3 entries all with IsOrange = true, I'm only getting 2 orange rows, the 1st and the 3rd, the second is Blue. This isn't a binding issue, it's an with the precedence for applying row style and alternating. Data driven styles should always win, which makes me thinking that it's a bug.

Comment: Five Minutes Please I Will Try Some Think

Comment: Are you sure your trigger gets called? Please try that first.

Comment: that is it, i have make small program and my data grid Worked good, i will add an answer

Comment: @inxs - there's only one way for a row to get orange - a trigger. if I see orange, it means it was called.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It's not a bug. In a `Style` you can't override a local value set for the alternating row. That's why this will not work

```
<DataGrid AlternatingRowBackground="Blue"
```

But if you set `AlternatingRowBackground` in a `Style` you can

```
<DataGrid.Style>
    <Style TargetType="DataGrid">
        <Setter Property="AlternatingRowBackground" Value="Blue"/>
    </Style>
</DataGrid.Style>
```

Thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12032637/620360).

Comment: Kind of agree, but it's counter intuitive that alternating row bg gets applied after the style.

Comment: Thanks!  This was exactly the solution I was looking for.

Comment: If not for this answer, I would never have figured it out.

Answer (score 2):

In my program I have two classes in addition to main window that contains one DataGird only. Let's start with first class:

MyClass.cs:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public bool IsOrange { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

I have only two properties, `IsOrange` specifies whether the row should be orange.
((Do not care for the other property.))

Now the view model class contains only collection of MyClass.

MyClassViewModel.cs:

```
public class MyClassViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<MyClass> con { get; set; }

    public MyClassViewModel()
    {
        con = new ObservableCollection<MyClass>();

        con.Add(new MyClass { IsOrange = true, Name = "Aa" });
        con.Add(new MyClass { IsOrange = true, Name = "Bb" });
        con.Add(new MyClass { IsOrange = false, Name = "Cc" });
        con.Add(new MyClass { IsOrange = false, Name = "Dd" });
        con.Add(new MyClass { IsOrange = false, Name = "Ee" });
        con.Add(new MyClass { IsOrange = true, Name = "Ff" });
        con.Add(new MyClass { IsOrange = true, Name = "Gg" });
        con.Add(new MyClass { IsOrange = false, Name = "Hh" });
    }
}
```

In MainWindow.xaml:

```
<Grid>
    <DataGrid Margin="10" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=con}" >
        <DataGrid.RowStyle>
            <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=IsOrange}" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Orange" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </DataGrid.RowStyle>
    </DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

finally in MainWindow.xaml.cs:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    MyClassViewModel VM = new MyClassViewModel();

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        DataContext = VM;
    }
}
```

and this is the result:

[image]

you can send me your email to send you the app.

Good Luck :)