# Changing Grid Row background color in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, grid

I want to set 2 colors to my grid rows, the even ones will have one color and the others will have another.
I dont know ho to even start of doing it.

```
<ListBox
    ItemsSource="{Binding}" x:Name="station_list"
    HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="378" Margin="10,31,0,0"
    VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="570" SelectedIndex="0">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid x:Name="Stations_Template">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="First Name: " />
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Path=sname}" />
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Text="Last Name: " />
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="3" Text="{Binding Path=mahoz}" />
                <CheckBox Grid.Column="4" Content="Is Active?"
                    IsEnabled="False"
                    IsChecked="{Binding Path=isactive}" />
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Comment: I think you are better off with a `DataGrid`. A `Grid` is a layout control.

Comment: Ditto w/ @Sjips http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13914382/wpf-datagrid-alternatingrowbackground-and-rowstyle-precedence

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Use Rectangles to fill the rows first, then add data to them.

```
    <Grid Background="White">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Rectangle Grid.Row="0" Fill="AliceBlue" />
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Text="Row 1" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
        <Rectangle Grid.Row="1" Fill="AntiqueWhite" />
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Text="Row 2" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
        <Rectangle Grid.Row="2" Fill="AliceBlue" />
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="2" Text="Row 3" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
        <Rectangle Grid.Row="3" Fill="AntiqueWhite" />
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="3" Text="Row 4" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
    </Grid>
```

Edit:
If you're loading an unknown amount of items, then i think you need something like an itemscontrol to load them in. You can then use the alternationcount and triggers to handle the alternating color.

```
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding DataList}" AlternationCount="2">
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid x:Name="FooBar" Margin="0,0,0,10">

                </Grid>
                <DataTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="ItemsControl.AlternationIndex" Value="0">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Blue" TargetName="FooBar"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="ItemsControl.AlternationIndex" Value="1">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" TargetName="FooBar"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </DataTemplate.Triggers>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
```

Comment: Hi, thank you, but the number of rows is unknown, it dynamic, I get it from the database

Comment: Updated answer for an unknown amount of rows

Comment: Thank you very much!!
WPF is way more better then WF, really need to dig into it

Comment: This is the way to go, obviously, but I suggest a minor improvement: put all of the rectangles before everything else in the grid, so they are actually in the background. Otherwise, you might have the "background" overlapping stuff from other rows, if that has either `RowSpan` greater than one or a negative (vertical) `Margin`.

Answer (score 10):

[image]

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication3.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Border Background="Cyan" />
        <Border Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1"  Background="Red" />
        <Border  Grid.Row="1" Background="Black" />
        <Border  Grid.Row="1" Background="Black" />
        <Border Grid.Row="2" Background="Orange" />
        <Border Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Background="Green" />
        <TextBlock Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Row="1" Text="Here is some more text" HorizontalAlignment="Center"  VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
        <TextBlock Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Text="Here is some text" HorizontalAlignment="Center"  VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
        <TextBlock Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Row="2" Text="Here is even more text" HorizontalAlignment="Center"  VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
![enter image description here][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LX9X8.png
```