# DataGrid -- AlternatingRowBackground color interfering with "IsMouseOver" color

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

I have a `DataGrid` that uses `AlternatingRowBackground` to make itself easier to read. In that same grid I also have a background color change for rows based on a `"IsMouseOver"` `Setter Property` in my `App.xaml` file. The problem that I am having is that the rows that have the alternating color (they are not white), do not change to the `"IsMouseOver"` color when the mouse hovers over it. Basically the `AlternatingRowBackground` color is taking precedence over my `RowStyle`. How do I make it so that the colored rows change as well when the mouse hovers over them?

App.xaml:

```
<!-- DataGrid Row Style -->
    <Style x:Key="RowStyleWithAlternation" TargetType="DataGridRow">
        <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True" />
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="GhostWhite"/>
        <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Normal"/>
        <Setter Property="ContextMenu" Value="{x:Null}"/>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="AlternationIndex" Value="1">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FFD0D0E0"/>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Purple"/>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="#F9F99F" />
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
```

User Control xaml:

```
<DataGrid ... AlternatingRowBackground="Gray" RowStyle="{StaticResource RowStyleWithAlternation}" ... />
```

Comment: Setting a property directly (AlternatingRowBackground="Gray") takes precedence over a trigger.   See the link mentioned by @Bruno for a longer discussion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works if you change your UserControl.xaml as follows:

```
<DataGrid RowStyle="{StaticResource RowStyleWithAlternation}" AlternationCount="2" />
```

The background is set through the AlternationIndex Trigger on your row which takes no priority over the IsMouseOver.

I've found the answer on this post:

[WPF Style Trigger for DataGridRow Background Color Trumped by AlternatingRowBackground Brush](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3614837/wpf-style-trigger-for-datagridrow-background-color-trumped-by-alternatingrowback)